# Rails database error and incorrect message displayed - Online course on Upskill

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

After creating a form for the "contact us" page, I have validated the form to display "Message sent" and "Error occurred" when it is completed or left incomplete respectively.

Now when I fill the form properly and press submit, it shows "Error occurred" when it shouldn't.

This is what the **terminal** says when I press submit -

```
Started GET "/contacts/new" for 180.151.19.136 at 2020-09-08 20:25:29 +0000
Cannot render console from 180.151.19.136! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
  Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 39.0ms)


Started POST "/contacts" for 180.151.19.136 at 2020-09-08 20:25:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 180.151.19.136! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"d6NOXW1mPMhhLExK/ltaYtCXWKykEcSXcGJv9O4eQ6NIDr9xmEDa+tqZmB0YdnThiydVWWoWGRGQ/8H9eR4ztw==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"okay okay"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to https://dfb077768d054560bf89dc972cd52d7c.vfs.butt9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/contacts/new
Completed 302 Found in 4ms


Started GET "/contacts/new" for 180.151.19.136 at 2020-09-08 20:25:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 180.151.19.136! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
  Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views: 50.1ms)
```

This is my *contact us* page code, **new.html.erb** -

```
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="row">
    
        <h3 class="text-center">Contact Us</h3>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
            
            <div class="well">
        
            <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.text_field :**name**,  class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :comments %>
                    <%= f.text_area :**name**,  class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                
                <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default'%>
            <% end %>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the **contact.rb** code -

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :comments, presence: true
  
end
```

And this is the code on my *controller file*, **contacts_controller.rb** -

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    
    def new
  @contact = Contact.new
    end
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
     redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
  else
     redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured."
  end
end
private
  def contact_params
     params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
  end
    
end
```

This is the code I found on **someone else's** contacts_controller file following the same course -

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  
  # GET request to /contact-us
  # Show new contact form
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
  
  # POST request /contacts
  def create
    # Mass assignment of form fields into contact object
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    # Save the Contact object to the database
    if @contact.save
      # Store form fields via parameters, into variables
      name = params[:contact][:name]
      email = params[:contact][:email]
      body = params[:contact][:comments]
      # Plug variables into Contact Mailer
      # email method and send email
      ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
      # Store success method in flash hash
      # and redirect to the new action
      flash[:success] = "Message sent."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      # If Contact object doesn't save,
      # render to the new action
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  private
  # To collect data from form, we need to use
  # strong parameters and white list form fields
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

All my work can be found [here](https://github.com/JuicingJ/upskill_saas_tutorial). Please let me know if you require any other information.

Thank you for your time and help.

**EDIT 1 -** So the error was in new.html.erb. f.text_field/area had
'name' instead of the respective label name.

I fixed that and used the code I provided above and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new
  if @contact.update(contact_params)
     redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
  else
     redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured."
  end
end
```

Comment: It did not work. The same error as before exists. I used someone else's contacts_controller code mentioned above and that also did not provide the desired result. Instead it pasted the comment field input in all the fields. And the terminal ran a post command as mentioned in the question. Please let me know what you think of this.

Answer (score 0):

So the error was in new.html.erb. f.text_field/area had 'name' instead of the respective label name.

I fixed that by replacing 'name' with 'email' and 'comments' respectively and used the code I provided above and it is working now.